# Converting Quote to Order

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, orders

I have a magento 1.7 shop and there been some issues with orders which are resolved but I need to restore some orders

I've written the following to try and display the orders

```
<?php 

require_once "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);   
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 


$order_id = 100001096; //use your own order id 
Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($order_id); //load order by order id 
$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 
foreach($ordered_items as $item){     //item detail     
    echo $item->getItemId(); //product id     
    echo $item->getSku();    
    echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); //ordered qty of item     
    echo $item->getName();     // etc. 
 } 
?>
```

However I'm getting

```
 mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/officestationerywarehouse.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 462
```

I'm unsure were I'm going wrong with this.

Update:
Just to note for people looking at this to try and find order from quotes. This code doesn't pull quotes only orders.

Comment: Hi, use Mage::app(); instead of Mage::init();

Comment: I tired this, but still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100001000 seem to be increment id and not order_id so try

```
require_once "../app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 
...
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
...
```

Comment: Anyway, there shouldn't be an exception when using method load with id 100001000

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175087/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getmodelinstance-on-a-non-object-in-ap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145373/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getmodelinstance-on-a-non-obje

Comment: I've changed the code as what you've suggested in the answer but still the same result, but a new error message "Call to a member function getAllItems() on a non-object on line 9" with line 9 being `$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();`

Comment: Try adding `umask(0);` see update to my anwser

Comment: Done the update and getting the following error `Warning: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined variable: order in find-item.php on line 13' in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 Stack trace: #0 /find-item.php(13): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 13, Array) #1 {main} thrown in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllItems() on a non-object in /find-item.php on line 13`

Comment: Updated code been added in place of the old code.

Comment: Sorry this should be $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

Comment: Just to note for people looking at this to try and find order from quotes. This code doesn't pull quotes only orders.